# How to redirect when a person tries to access a webpage directly from URL, But should work when accessed through a button click

Tags: php

I have no Knowledge about PHP, However, I'd like to make a webpage inaccessable directly through a link, But should work when accessed through a button click on a previous page.

NOTE: I do not have any Db or it's not any login based website.

I just want a simple PHP integration, Can anyone help me with this? :)

Comment: AFAIK there is no standard mechanism to achieve this. It would help if you describe what & why are you actually trying to achieve.
If you are eg. loading page content via AJAX then browser sends headers using which you can then decide whether to return or not the content, or to eg redirect user somewhere else.
Without more info it's hard to answer

Comment: `inaccessable directly through a link, But should work when accessed through a button click on a previous page.`...why would that matter? As others have said, please explain the context more clearly.

Comment: Nothing login related, it's just that I want a page to open only if clicked from another specific source and nothing else. I am going to explain, It is because, I have a page that is only accessable by a few specified people, And it redirects to a page, Again, Only these specific users have access to, But I want them to go through the full process of accessing the second page through the first but not directly through a bookmark or a link.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to learn PHP to work with PHP.

However the techniques you seem to be looking for should be listed in the [prevention section of the CSRF Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention). Cross-Site Request Forgery defense mechanisms usually force you to visit a page and send a request with information from that page. Therefor without visiting the page you cannot directly access the second resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] super global variable. It tells if you came from a referer URL, or opened directly, like from a button.

```
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) && $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]){
    // User came from another source
    require __DIR__ . "/denyaccess.php";
}
else{
    // User clicked the button to open fresh
    require __DIR__ . "/realpage.php";
}
```

However, I have a feeling you are trying something URL affiliation? In that case, this is not the right approach. Rather try using some code as URL argument/parameter to check the accessibility source.

Comment: Bear in mind that the referer value can be spoofed easily. So it can't be used for any actual security, and also it often isn't populated at all

Comment: @ADyson Yes, that is true, not a reliable approach of course, but a dirty quick.